Is "I am all against it" a counterpart of "I am all for it"?
Tom said "I want to go into business"
His wife answered "I am all for it".
"All" here is an adverb and it means completely.
Similarly, can Tom's wife say "I am all against it"?

Generally, we just say: I'm against it.

Yes, we can say to be against something , but I'm all for it is a common idiom and this Ngram shows that I'm all against it is very much less common.

CHatGPT says "all against" is not idiomatic. it suggests using "completely against". But "I am completely against it*" is as rare as  "I am all against it*"
